# OTA distribution of IPA for iOS 7.1.2 and above

Tags: ios, ssl, certificate, mamp

I am trying to share the enterprise iOS app to my testers for testing through  OTA distribution of IPA . I have hosted it on the local server (MAMP) in my machine . I tried by changing my plist file like this (http to https)

```
itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://example.com/manifest.plist
```

but no use its not getting downloded same error message .I installed that app in the same iPad using iTunes and it works like that . I want to set up SSL certicate in my local server (MAMP) how to do that . please help me if anyone knows so that i can host IPA with SSL .

Comment: As a temporary solution you could host the file on dropbox, just change the link from https://www.dropbox.com/myApp to https://dl.dropbox.com/myApp

Comment: our company will not prefer dropbox  please provide me with another solution